# Recommended way for custom notification format mechanism?

Tags: python-3.x, architecture, implementation

I'm trying to implement a notification service. I've written functions that contain business logics and return notifications to fan out.

Given that notifications might be sent to different applications, customized notification message format must be generated.For instance, some channels require html while some require markdown.

I kinda feel handling format with if conditions is not easily expandable and has a bad code smell, yet I can't come up with a better approach nor can I find examples after googling, I'm wondering how is this sort of custom formatting implemented in large companies' notification system or if any design pattern/examples/tutorials are recommended.

```python
# handler.py
from functions import func1
from channel import MyChannelClass

class NotificationHandler:
    def __init__(self, channels: List[MyChannelClass]):
        self.channels = channels

    def generate_notifications(self):
        while True:
            notifications = []
            notifications += func1(self.channels)

            # send notifications to kafka topic and some worker process will fan out
                        
            time.sleep(10800)

# functions.py

def func1(channels):

    # complex business logic here and gets a list of metadata
    # mocked as below variable, only a few fields are listed for demo

    metadata = [
        {'to':'receiver', 'from':'sender1', 'title':'title1'},
        {'to':'receiver', 'from':'sender1', 'title':'title2'}    
    ]
    
    notifications = []

    for channel in channels:
        for m in metadata:
            if channel.format == 'markdown':
                notifications.append({'channel':channel.type, 'to':m['to'], 'title':m['title'], msg:'This is an **important** message'})

            if channel.format == 'html':
                notifications.append({'channel':channel.type, 'to':m['to'], 'title':m['title'], msg:'<h2>This is an <b>important</b> message</h2>'})

    return notifications
```